# Android activity transition effect

Tags: android, android-activity, transition

I want to make a transition in my android from one activity to another like this:

[image: image 1]:

I try with `overridePendingTransition()` but i think it's impossible. I also see `ViewFlipper` but i can't use activity with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ViewPager](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html) might be what you are looking for. It does not involve multiple activities though, i.e. you stay withing a single activity.

Answer (score 2):

A `ViewFipper` is not used to switch between Activities.  To implement a custom transition, you would call `overridePendingTransition(int enterAnim, int exitAnim)` in the new Activity's `oncreate()` method.  Both parameters would be a reference to an animation saved `res/anim` folder ([link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html#View)).